# Should I make a new managedObjectContext for each ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I was wondering what was the best practice for doing the `managedObjectContext`. When I first started learning swift / iOS / Xcode earlier this year I was putting this line in every class for the ViewControllers / TableViewControllers.

`let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`

And everything was working correctly. But then I thought I read something at some point that said to use the same `managedObjectContext` for every ViewController / TableViewController. And I interpreted this to mean to send my original moc variable to each ViewController / TableViewController. To do this I started sending it in the 'prepareForSegue' function. So only the first view had the code above, and everything else just had `var moc: NSManagedObjectContext?` that would get set from the `prepareForSegue` Function.

But the more I learn, I'm starting to think that the AppDelegate is creating the actual `managedObjectContext` and the `let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext` line is just setting that `managedObjectContext` to the moc variable, and not actually making a new `managedObjectContext`.

So should I be continuing to use the `prepareForSegue` function to send my moc variable to all the linked ViewControllers / TableViewControllers, or should I not worry about it and be setting it using the code at the top?

Thank you.

Comment: You are almost certainly correct about the AppDelegate creating one object and passing you a reference.  **In my opinion**, though, view controllers really shouldn't know the mechanics of how their data is acquired.  You might want to look at MVC structure where a Model object is responsible for the data and controllers communicate with it, sending changes and receiving current state.

Comment: If you're interested you might watch https://realm.io/news/slug-marcus-zarra-exploring-mvcn-swift/ Briefly mentions different methods for handling the `managedObjectContext` but speaks to your larger question about app architecture.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

this is perfectly fine as it does not create a new context, but just gives you a new reference to the same context. In fact it is in no way different from "sending original moc variable in the 'prepareForSegue' function". You're doing exactly the same thing in two different ways, that's it.

Read about value and reference types in Swift: [Classes and structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was getting tedious trying to send the same moc variable through my whole app.